# Why am I getting a different value for the percent variation explained by my dbRDA output?

Tags: summary, variance, vegan

I've run a dbRDA on a large community abundance dataset in Vegan, and have realised I'm getting different values for the total variance explained by my constrained axis.

If I use summary(dbrda) I get a smaller value than if I call the dbrda model directly. Anyone have an idea why this is happening and which value is correct?

[summary call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDGEU.png)

[direct call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdIAs.png)

The rsqaured value also comes back as 42%...

Comment: Can you show the actual call to `capscale()`. It's not clear to me why one reports a non-Euclidean component (Imaginary) and the other doesn't.

Comment: NB the imaginary component in direct call: the one with negative eigenvalues. Naturally, you should *not* use capscale, and in particularly, you should not call it dbrda. If you want to have dbrda, you should use function dbrda() instead of capscale().